# What is the use of pd.concat's copy=True?

Tags: python, copy, concatenation, pandas

I read the following about the copy-parameter in pandas.concat function [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

> **copy**: bool, default True
> If False, do not copy data unnecessarily.

Questions:

1. Why would anyone want to copy data unnecessarily? (which appearantly happens because the default is `True`)
2. Are there any downsides setting `copy=False`?

Comment: Considering the case when you have multi large dataframes, and not enough memory, you many want to just concat dataframes without deep-copy

Answer (score 4):

> well see there are 2 type of copies in python
>
> 1.Deep copy
>
> 2.Shallow Copy

so basically the copy parameter in `pd.concat()` defines the same by default it creates a `deep copy` but if you overwrite its value by `False` it creates `Shallow copy`

**Note:-In `deep copy` a exact copy is created so if you make any changes in original variable it doesn't reflect in your copy but in `shallow copy` it reflect in your copy because in `shallow copy` the data is referencing to original data**

Comment: Ok I understand, so `copy=False` can be used with no problems in cases like: `df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1, copy=False)` because the original will be overwritten anyway.

Comment: well I don't think so `copy=False`  will cause any problem untill you make any change in the original values data